# DigitalOcean Rake db:seed command not found

Tags: database, web, rake, dbmigrate

I am trying to update my database, which is stored at a DigitalOcean-server. The seeds.rb-file is on the server atm, but I don't know what to type in the console window. When I type "rake db:seed", I get "Command not found". I would have been very thankful if you could help me! :-)

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=<your environment>` ?

Comment: I get the same "command not found"-message when I type that. Is there a specific directory that I have to be in?

Comment: You have to be in your project's root directory.